# How to scale DynamoDB record processing?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, scaling

I'm building a web-based CRON service using DynamoDB and Lambda. While I don't currently have the following problem, I'm curious about how I could solve it if it arises.

The architecture works like this:

1. Lambda A - query for all tasks that should occur in the current minute
2. Lambda A - for each task, increment a counter on the document
3. Lambda B - listen for the stream event for each document and run the actual CRON task

As far as I can tell, Lambda B should be scalable - AWS should run as many instances as needed to process all the stream events (I think).

But for Lambda A, say I have 1 billion documents that need to be processed each minute.

When I query for each minute's tasks, the Lambda will need to make multiple requests in order to fetch & update all the documents.

How could I architect the system such that all the documents get processed in < 60 seconds?

Comment: Hi marclar, when you say query for all tasks that should occur in the current minute? you re quering a table in dynamoDB with time = current minute?

Comment: Exactly, @wpp - I don't think provisioned throughput is the thing I'm looking for. When I execute a query that has 999,999,999 results, and there's a maximum size of 1MB per "page" of results, how can I be sure that enough Lambdas are spawned to take care of that # of records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, Lambda A would have to do a monster scan/query which wouldn't scale.

One way to architect this to make this work would be to partition your cron items so that you can invoke multiple lambdas in parallel (i.e. fan out the work) instead of just one (lambda A) so that each one handles a partition (or set of partitions) instead of the whole thing.

How you achieve this depends on what your current primary key looks like and how else you expect to query these items. Here's one solution:

```
cronID | rangeKey               | jobInfo | counter
1001   | 72_2020-05-05T13:58:00 | foo     | 4
1002   | 99_2020-05-05T14:05:00 | bar     | 42
1003   | 01_2020-05-05T14:05:00 | baz     | 0
1004   | 13_2020-05-05T14:10:00 | blah    | 2
1005   | 42_2020-05-05T13:25:00 | 42      | 99
```

I've added a random prefix (00-99) to the rangeKey, so you can have different lambdas query different sets of items in parallel based on that prefix.

In this example you could invoke 100 lambdas each minute (the "Lambda A" types), with each handling a single prefix set. Or you could have say 5 lambdas, with each handling a range of 20 prefixes. You could even dynamically scale the number of lambda invocations up and down depending on load, without having to update the prefixes in your data in your table.

Since these lambdas are basically the same, you could just invoke lambda A the required number of times, injecting the appropriate prefix(es) for each one as a config.

#### EDIT

Re the 1MB page limit in your comment, you'll get a `LastEvaluatedKey` back if your query has been limited. Your lambda can execute queries in a loop, passing the `LastEvaluatedKey` value back as `ExclusiveStartKey` until you've got all the result pages.

You'll still need to be careful of running time (and catching errors to retry since this is not atomic) but fanning your lambdas as above will deal with the running time if you fan it widely enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your project but looks like what you are asking is already in the [AWS DynamoDb Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughput.html), read here:

> When you create a new provisioned table in Amazon DynamoDB, you must
>   specify its provisioned throughput capacity. This is the amount of
>   read and write activity that the table can support. DynamoDB uses this
>   information to reserve sufficient system resources to meet your
>   throughput requirements.
>
> You can create an **[on-demand mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html#HowItWorks.OnDemand)** table instead so that you don't have
>   to manage any capacity settings for servers, storage, or throughput.
>   DynamoDB instantly accommodates your workloads as they ramp up or down
>   to any previously reached traffic level. If a workload’s traffic level
>   hits a new peak, DynamoDB adapts rapidly to accommodate the workload.
>   For more information
>
> You can optionally allow **[DynamoDB auto scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AutoScaling.html)** to manage your table's
>   throughput capacity. However, you still must provide initial settings
>   for read and write capacity when you create the table. DynamoDB auto
>   scaling uses these initial settings as a starting point, and then
>   adjusts them dynamically in response to your application's
>   requirements
>
> As your application data and access requirements change, you might
>   need to adjust your table's throughput settings. If you're using
>   DynamoDB auto scaling, the throughput settings are automatically
>   adjusted in response to actual workloads. You can also use the
>   UpdateTable operation to manually adjust your table's throughput
>   capacity. You might decide to do this if you need to bulk-load data
>   from an existing data store into your new DynamoDB table. You could
>   create the table with a large write throughput setting and then reduce
>   this setting after the bulk data load is complete.
>
> You specify throughput requirements in terms of capacity units—the
>   amount of data your application needs to read or write per second. You
>   can modify these settings later, if needed, or enable DynamoDB auto
>   scaling to modify them automatically.

I hope this can help your doubt.